# Android Studio Accessing Database problem

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

Hey I am trying to access my sqlite database from android studio using device explorer. But when opening the data folder I get this error:
[error_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ao7BH.png)

I am using a physical device connected to my pc.

Comment: You have not even mentioned your error.

Comment: @blackappsthe error is in the image. Thats the only error.

Comment: Even now you did not mention the error. You should mention the error in the text and subject of your post was the hint. In your post. Also not as comment. Error??? What error! Problem? What problem!